# CrawlSpider: Ignore URL before request

Tags: scrapy

I have a CrawlSpider derived spider. When the url has a certain format, it does a callback to a function named parse_item.

```
rules = (
    Rule( 
        LinkExtractor( 
            allow=('/whatever/', )
        )
    ), 

    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            allow=('/whatever/detailpage/1234/')
        ), 
        callback='parse_item'
    ),
)
```

I have a status only_new=True for my spider. When this state is enabled, I don`t want to crawl urls which are already in my database.

I would like to check the url BEFORE the request is done, because when I have 5 new detailpages I want to crawl but 1000 detailpages I don`t want to crawl, i want to send 5 requests instead of 1000.

But in the callback funtion, the request has already been done. I would like to do something like following:

```
rules = (
   (...)

    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            allow=('/whatever/detailpage/1234/')
        ), 
        callback_before_request='check_if_request_is_nessesary'
    ),
)

def check_if_request_is_nessesary(spider, url):
    if spider.only_new and url_exists_in_database():
        raise IgnoreRequest
    else:
        do_request_and_call_parse_item(url)
```

Is this possible with a middleware or something?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`process_links` attribute for the Rule](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule) -- it allows you to specify a callable or a method name to be used for filtering the list of [`Link`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/link.py#L10) objects returned by the [`LinkExtractor`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.contrib.linkextractors).

Your code would look something like this:

```
rules = (
   (...)

    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            allow=('/whatever/detailpage/1234/')
        ), 
        process_links='filter_links_already_seen'
    ),
)

def filter_links_already_seen(self, links):
    for link in links:
        if self.only_new and url_exists_in_database(link.url):
            continue
        else:
            yield link
```